# How to change signal value instatntly?

Tags: vhdl

```
if(rising_edge(clk)) then        
  count := count + 1;
  if count = 3 then
    enable <= 1;
  elsif count = 6 then
    enable <= 0;
    count := 0;             
  end if;
end if;

if enable = 0 then
  a0i <= a_0;
  boi <= b_0;
end if;

if enable = 1 then
  a0i <= a_1;
  boi <= b_1;
end if;
```

All are signals except the count. Value of a0i and boi should response as soon as enable becomes either 0 or 1. I tried using the variable. but it can not allow me to use out side the process. 
[I am getting the o/p as this. How ever I want to change the input as soon as enable signal change.](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzwiDetjjG_QQ0FlWmFYUkNIbFE/edit)

Comment: Have you set a default value for `enable` and `count`? Please, post your complete process-block. Note `enable` will be translated to a register, so there is a delay between comparison and setting enable to a value. Additionally, the change of enable can not be evaluate in the same cycle, because it's a signal.

Comment: From your simulation waveform, it  looks to me like you failed to include `enable`, `a_0`, `b_0`, `a_1`, and `b_1` in your sensitivity list, but I can't be sure because you didn't post the complete example. Because you test their values outside of the `rising_edge(clk)`, they need to be included. Also, you could use an `else` instead of a separate test for `enable = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the last two if conditions in another process

```
Process(enable, a_0, b_0, a_1, b_1)
begin 
  If(enable = '0')THEN
       a0i <= ...
       ....
  ELSE
        .....
END IF;
END PROCESS;
```

This process is sensitive to the enable signal so anytime there is a change in enable, independent of the clock, the statements will take effect immediately (asynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: use 2 processes as blueprint mentioned.

Solution 2: use an internal variable.

```
process(clk)
  variable count    : natural range of 0 to 6   := 0;
  variable enable_i : std_logic                 := '0';
begin
  if(rising_edge(clk)) then      
    count := count + 1;
    if count = 3 then
      enable_i := '1';
    elsif count = 6 then
      enable_i := '0';
      count    := 0;                
    end if;
  end if;

  if enable = '0' then
    a0i <= a_0;
    boi <= b_0;
  else
    a0i <= a_1;
    boi <= b_1;
  end if;

  enable <= enable_i;
end process;
```

Some hints:

- Maybee, the type boolean is more suitable for your signal/variable `enable_i`
- If `enable_i` is only used inside the process, then you can remove the conversion to `enable`
- including the data path and multiplexers in a state machine (I assume this is a part of it) is not a good design choice.

Comment: After mixing your suggestion and blueprint's suggestion , it's worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also take these two equation below out from your process.

```
process(...)
 [...]
 if enable = 0 then
   a0i <= a_0;
   boi <= b_0;
 end if;

 if enable = 1 then
   a0i <= a_1;
   boi <= b_1;
 end if;
end process
```

Then you cannot use the IF statement anymore, but you can use the WHEN statement :

```
a0i <= a_0 when enable = '0' else a_1;
boi <= b_0 when enable = '0' else b_1;
```

Note that in this case, the multiplexer will be after the latch. This could be important if you have timing issues on these signals.

Comment: @Raviraj This is strange. What kind of error do you get ? Did you set these line outside of a process as mentionned ? Maybe you could try adding brackets around (enable = '0') but I'm not sure its be better.

Answer (score 0):

From your simulation waveform, it  looks to me like you failed to include `enable`, `a_0`, `b_0`, `a_1`, and `b_1` in your sensitivity list, but I can't be sure because you didn't post the complete example. Because you test the values of the 5 mentioned signals outside of the `if rising_edge(clk)`, they need to be included. The values are only updated on the falling edge of `clk` because, presuming that `clk` is the only thing in your sensitivity list, that is the next time the process is evaluated.

It should be otherwise functional as written, although you could use an `else` instead of a separate test for `enable = 0` for a slight readability improvement. Synthesis usually ignores the sensitivity list (it just makes simulation more efficient) so it should already work if you were to synthesize.